# jQuery dynamic input field focus

Tags: jquery, focus, jquery-click-event, input-field

I want to add an input field  dynamically to my page using the following jQuery:

```
var inputNode = "<input id='inputNode' class='tiContent' type='text'
    placeholder='text input...'/>";
$("div").append(inputNode);
```

and after doing so, I want the input field to have focus with blinking text cursor, so I want to type in it right after creation.

Could someone please tell me how can I do this?

I've tried calling

`$(inputNode).focus()`

and also have tried

`$(inputNode).trigger('click')`

but none of them worked. I can type into the field after clicking in it, but as I've said I want to type without any interaction immediately.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you tried `$(inputNode).focus()`, jQuery was simply building a new disconnected (from the DOM) `<input>` element which was different to the one you had appended - although this disconnected one was focussed :-)

There are a couple of ways to focus the input.

If you can use HTML5 then adding the `autofocus` attribute will focus the input

```
var inputNode = '<input autofocus id="inputNode" class="tiContent" type="text" placeholder="text input..."/>';
$('div').append(inputNode);
```

Or, using jQuery, you need to find the `<input>` *after* the element has been created to call [`.focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) on it, as the `inputNode` in your code is simply a string and not a jQuery object.

```
var inputNode = '<input id="inputNode" class="tiContent" type="text" placeholder="text input..."/>';
$('div').append(inputNode);
$('div input').focus(); // or $('#inputNode').focus();
```

Comment: Many thanks! This is the 3rd correct way to do it, you were really helpful, all of you!

Comment: This one does not work for me because when $('div input').focus(); is run, the element seems not to exist.

Comment: Autofocus only works for the first textbox, and focus works all the time for me.

Answer (score 4):

inputNode isn't a jQuery element, it's a string.

You probably mean:

```
$('#inputNode').focus()
```

as opposed to:

```
$(inputNode).focus()
```

The browser won't grumble at this since you've got a variable with that name

Comment: Hi there!
Many thanks, it works.
I thought that the surrounding it by $() will cast it to a jQuery object. (I'm pretty new to this stuff).

thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

You need something like this:

```
 $('<input />').appendTo('div').get(0).focus();
```

The focus method is a method of the DOM element *not* the jQuery object hence the need for a call to 'get'.

You might like to read up on the [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) and [get](http://api.jquery.com/get/) methods in the jQuery docs

Hope this helps

Comment: This one worked out of the box for me.  I used it as such: `$('<input >').appendTo('.class').typeahead([{...}]).get(0).focus();`

Comment: $(html), appending it using append(), then calling focus on the object... doesn't work. Same thing only using appendTo instead: did work. Get did not appear to be required, just calling appendTo.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert it into a jQuery object before appending it to the dom, that way you have a reference to it. Then just call `.focus` on the referenced object.

```
var $inputNode = $("<input id='inputNode' class='tiContent' type='text' placeholder='text input...'/>");
$('body').append($inputNode);​​​
​$inputNode.focus();​
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9V8r9/).

Comment: Thanks, now I know how to convert a html element given in String to jQuery object.

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="button" value="click me" id="btnCreateTxt" />
<div></div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnCreateTxt').click(function() {        
        var inputNode = $("<input id='inputNode' class='tiContent' type='text' placeholder='text input...'/>");
        $("div").append(inputNode);
        inputNode.focus();    
    });
});
```

works good for me: http://jsfiddle.net/GqFap/9/